# Windows 7 and the case of the missing regtlib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-7, regtlib

**I've just discovered that regtlib.exe appears to be missing from Windows 7** (and apparently from Vista as well).

I've just installed Windows 7 RC in a VM and I'm attempting to build our existing projects on the new OS. The projects are c/c++ based and I'm using visual studio 2008. In order to build these projects I need to register several tlb files that are referenced within the code base.

Has anyone also encountered this problem? And, has anyone managed to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah regtlib was removed from vista and up. As far as I know, all it does is call LoadTypeLibEx with the `REGKIND_REGISTER` flag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221249.aspx). Maybe you could write a simple replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I see a little console app in my future. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this issue (couldn't add any components to a VB6 project on Win7).  This post ([Error accessing the system registry in VB 6 IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104383/error-accessing-the-system-registry-in-vb-6-ide)) pointed to regtlib (which is missing from Win7).  I just 
set the VB6 start menu icon to 'Run As Administrator' and it worked fine for adding components and should fix any problems relating to updating the registry as well.

Regards

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Finally got back to trying to build our code base on windows 7. Anyway, I went back to the installer for one of the dependencies that was causing me grief. The error message from the installer wasn't to helpful but it did point to a regasm that was being run from inside the installer.

I ran the regasm command from a cmd prompt and got more information. It appears that you need administrative credentials to perform this task and our current installers don't do the privilege escalation properly.

So, long story short, I got dlls registered and the build appears to be working.